# How to display PDF File without plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I need something like Google offers with `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=`.

Here an example:
https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf

This is perfect. It works on mobile, works with `.docs` files etc. Just awesome.

But the problem with this solution:

- File has to be public
- You don't know what Google does with this file
- (Limited queries)

I just need a modern way do display PDF (or maybe even .docs etc.) files.
Or is `<embed>` and `<object>` the only really working option.

It should work on all browsers and mobile.

Edit: Not sure, why the downvote. If this is a noob question I am sorry but I am a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Opening PDFs in browser can be accomplished with PDF.js

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

It's the standard way Firefox presents PDFs inline. For doc-files you have to do some kind of conversion: In order to view doc-files I would convert a requested file to a pdf in the backend like posted here:

https://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support   so it is not working fully in all browsers.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/master/web/compatibility.js   This file adds additional compatiblity to pdf.js. you should give it a try

Comment: you can fully customize the output as it is open source

Comment: Just a correction; PDF.JS does not work in all browsers and mobile devices, it works on _most_ browsers. Complex documents will render poorly in mobile devices.

Comment: FYI, Whilst PDF is a standard, a .docx is still considered proprietary and there could be legal and accessibility issues with using non-standard file formats.